# Excel file not getting uploaded when application deployed on IIS 6.1 SP1 on windows server 2008 r2

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have a server 2008 r2 where I have an application which takes input as excel file. I have MS Office 2002 on that machine. When I run the project locally the excel file gets uploaded but when I deploy the application on IIS 6.1 and run the app and try to upload the excel sheet, it gives me an error " Please upload proper excel ". I guess the error is occurring because it is not recognizing the .xls file format. Any idea what is going wrong.?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. The Server was 64 bit and using IIS 6.1 was not getting compatible.  So ran the following script in cmd and its done. Now I am able to upload my excel file.

```
cscript %SystemDrive%\inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs set w3svc/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```